# Every requests should contain a server IP

Tags: php

I have file which is hosted on external web service - URL: http://external-service.com/file.flv

This file can be download only from IP of my web service.
Every visitor should can download this file but how while every visitor has other IP address than IP of my server?

I could use a CURL but request from CURL is going to server, not to visitor. I can't use:

```
echo $response_from_curl;
```

because this file is very large. My server has max_execution_file - 450 seconds. It's not enough.

I could use:

```
header("Location: http://external-service.com/file.flv");
```

but in this example, file can't be downlaod because redirect is from visitor IP so it's bad idea too.

Can I hide real user IP in this example and make a request from user browser using server IP?

Maybe someone know how I can solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What web server are you using? Sounds like you need to proxy the requests and that does not need to be done in PHP.

Comment: If you want the client to download the file (bc it's too big), you can't check for the server IP....

Answer (score 1):

Your server has to download this file and show it to the user with the correct headers.

**Little example:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: video/flv");
$file_url = "http://external-service.com/file.flv";
echo file_get_contents($file_url);
?>
```

I recommend to use curl.

**Example with curl:**

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: video/flv");
    $file_url = "http://external-service.com/file.flv";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file_url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: This file has more than 1GB... I can't download this file in  these ways because my server has max_execution_file - 450 seconds. It's not enough. I need a solution, which can download a file from external server directly to visitor browser

Comment: Can't be done external server directly to your visitors browser if only your server ip has access. If the external server is your server too you will have to grant temporary access for visitors.

Comment: Here is a problem... External service is not mine. So it cannot be done, yes?

Comment: No, if the external server is not yours it can't be done without downloading the files like in the examples above.

Comment: Maybe I can change an IP addresses of visitors and then use something like this:
header("Location: http://external-serivice.com/file.flv") ?

Comment: You are not able to change the visitors IP. The code you show me is just a redirection. Maybe an idea to host the flv file yourself?

Comment: I can't host this movies because it's more than 1000 movies.
Maybe my server should use a PROXY, and then every visitor should use the same proxy and finally everything should work?